# Pandas: How to conditionally sum values in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes:

```
df1
    Name        Leads
0   City0       22
1   City1       11
2   City2       28
3   City3       15
4   City4       14
5   City5       15
6   City6       25

df2
    Name        Leads
0   City1       13
1   City2       0
2   City4       2
3   City6       5
```

I'd like to sum the values in the Leads columns only when the values in the Name columns match. I've tried:

```
df3 = df1['Leads'] + df2['Leads'].where(df1['Name']==df2['Name'])
```

which returns the error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Have looked at similar issues on StackOverflow but none fit my specific use. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Assume `df2.Name` values are unique and `df2` has exact 2 columns as your sample. Let's try something different by using `map` and `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

df1.Leads + df1.Name.map(defaultdict(int, df2.to_numpy()))

Out[38]:
0    22
1    24
2    28
3    15
4    16
5    15
6    30
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `merge`

```
df = df1.merge(df2,on='Name', how='left')
df['Leads']=df['Leads_x'].add(df['Leads_y'],fill_value=0)
df
Out[9]: 
    Name  Leads_x  Leads_y  Leads
0  City0       22      NaN   22.0
1  City1       11     13.0   24.0
2  City2       28      0.0   28.0
3  City3       15      NaN   15.0
4  City4       14      2.0   16.0
5  City5       15      NaN   15.0
6  City6       25      5.0   30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='left',on=['Name']).set_index(['Name']).sum(1).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    Name     0
0  City0  22.0
1  City1  24.0
2  City2  28.0
3  City3  15.0
4  City4  16.0
5  City5  15.0
6  City6  30.0
```

You can remove `how` argument if you only want the matching elements, resulting this output:

```
    Name   0
0  City1  24
1  City2  28
2  City4  16
3  City6  30
```

If you have more columns than `Name` in your actual case that you wish not to sum, include them all as index right before sum.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to python. I am pretty sure there are people who can solve it in a better way. The below solution somehow worked when I tried on my system. You can give it a try too.

```
for i in df2.Name:
    temp = df1[df1.Name==i].Leads.sum() + df2[df2.Name==i].Leads.sum()
    df1.loc[df1.Name ==i, 'Leads'] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a `merge` and `sum` across the columns:

```
df1['Leads'] = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='outer').filter(like='Lead').sum(1)

    Name    Leads
0   City0   22.0
1   City1   24.0
2   City2   28.0
3   City3   15.0
4   City4   16.0
5   City5   15.0
6   City6   30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df1.set_index('Name').add(df2.set_index('Name')).dropna().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Name  Leads
0  City1   24.0
1  City2   28.0
2  City4   16.0
3  City6   30.0
```

Using data alignment by setting indexes on the dataframes and dropping nan values where indexes don't match from df2.